# ad sextam in tertiis et totis duplicibus

Tags: medieval-latin

This is a rubric (instruction) for when to sing a hymn.  I translated it as "At Sext on third and all doubles."  This doesn't seem right to me because the 'third' is redundant.  I would like to know what the literal translation is.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you could give us a little more context. Where did you get this phrase? What book is it from? When was it published?

It literally means "At Sext on Thirds and all Doubles". I know what Doubles are, they are a kind of feast with a high liturgical rank. I do not know what Thirds might be.

Update: Thanks for the context supplied in your comment below. It confirms in my mind what Brianpck said. There is apparently something called a "Third Double" as well as something called a "Complete Double". I've never heard these terms before, and I cannot tell you what they mean.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  It is a rubric for the hymn Rector potens, verax Deus found in a catalogue of medieval music: Die mittelalterlichen Hymnenmelodien des Abendlandes.  There is a similar one for Rerum Deus tenax vigor: ad nonam in tertiis duplicibus.  Yes, the 'tertiis' part is where I am confused.

Comment: I believe both "tertiis" and "totis" modify "duplicibus" as adjectives, i.e. "on tertiary and complete doubles." I found a French work where this was translated as "doubles complets" (complete doubles) and "troisièmes doubles" (third doubles). It appears to be a very old (perhaps pre-16th c.) designation of liturgical feasts, and perhaps it's even peculiar to a religious order.

Comment: @brianpck I think you've nailed it. Do you want to make it the answer?

Comment: Under 'Ranking of liturgical days' Wikipedia has 
Doubles, I Class;  Doubles, II Class; Greater Doubles; Doubles;  Semidoubles. and then, in 1911, 1955, 1960, 1969 simplifications and renaming.

Comment: @Hugh I think even that belies the complexity: here's a good Catholic Encyclopedia article that includes a few lists of different terms used: https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06021b.htm